# How can I create new image uploder field while add or edit any product in magento2?

Tags: file-upload, magento2

I want to create a custom image uploader after the product name and want to display a preview of the uploaded image (in jpg,jpeg,png all type) in the magento2 admin panel. How can I do this? (In addition, if the image is stored in any directory in my local system this will be more helpful).

[Image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx3sd.png) I want this field after the product name.

My **Cutomimageupload/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="custom_image_upload">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image Upload</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="custom_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/product_gallery/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My **Cutomimageupload/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_new.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_form">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content" name="product_form_gallery_content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Image</item>
                        <item name="elementName" xsi:type="string">custom_image</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_image</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I want to create new field after product name with image uploder.

Please comment if you have any idea how to achieve this functionality.

Thanks